# Xfinium vertical text in table cell

Tags: c#, .net, pdf

Is there a possibility in Xfinium to draw text vertically in a table cell like in the example below

[image: example]

I see there is the ability to provide rotation on text drawing using `Rotation` property of `PdfStringLayoutOptions`, but I'm not sure how I can use it inside the table cell.

Answer (score 1):

The only solution at this moment is to create a form XObject, draw the rotated text on it (xobject.Graphics.DrawString) and then include the form XObject in the table through a form XObject cell.

Disclaimer: I work for the company that develops [XFINIUM.PDF](https://xfiniumpdf.com).